# Set default profile in Firefox via command-line

Tags: firefox, command-line

I'm trying to pre-setup a new Firefox  installation with a custom user.js. However, no profile is made until Firefox is first run, unless you run this command:
`Firefox.exe -CreateProfile <NAME>`

Problem is, even if this command is run, Firefox will still create and launch with the default-release profile. Is there any way to set a default profile via the command line or by modifying a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Process Monitor to see what it does when changing default profile.

In *%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini* there's a `Default=<Profile Path>` line. Replace
<Profile Path> with your desired profile's path, which should be included in that file as well.

Ex.

```
Profiles/bd3a3mdf.default-release
```